# Gigabyte G5 browser freeze on Ctrl+s

Tags: ubuntu, freeze, browser

I have a problem with my Ubuntu 22. When I open Firefox or Chrome and press <kbd>Ctrl+s</kbd> to save a page, the window for saving keeps opening, thus filling up my RAM completely and making my laptop freeze. I am using a Gigabyte G5 laptop, i5-11400H/16GB/512GB/3050 4GB.

Did anyone have this problem?

I tried a few browsers, and all have the same issue.  I updated both Mozilla and Chrome to the latest versions available, and I updated Ubuntu to the latest version too.

Comment: It may have something to do with the web page you're trying to save. Is it very big?

Comment: Nope, it's first page after searching in browser

Comment: Since there is no link to an example page, there is no way for us to replicate the issue for ourselves. It is, therefore, a bit difficult to point to any specific cause for your issue.

Comment: Ok, here it is, but it happens whatever page is.

https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&q=stackoverflow

Comment: Have you tried after limiting the number of threads your browser can spawn to the very strict minimum ?

Comment: I have the same problem on Ubuntu 22, Gigabyte G5 laptop, when I press ctrl+s in the Chrome/Firefox browser, a lot of file dialogs open, as if I keep pressing the keys

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here.
The bug is with every page in Firefox.
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> (save file as) opens infinite dialogs and Firefox is freezing.

File save as (in the menu) works ok. Only the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> shortcut is buggy.

Running Firefox 107.0.1 (64-bit) Snap for Ubuntu